# What is "employer letter" for Schengen when I'm in college?

Tags: schengen, germany, paperwork

One of the [requirements](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Tourist__Visa.html) to apply for a Schengen visa to Germany from the US is

> - reference letter from your employer

I'm a student in a university. Do I just need a document confirming that I'm enrolled as a student? Or something more?

Comment: How long are you staying?  In most cases US nationals don't need any visa at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind the employment letter is *strong ties to your home country and steady income*, and since you are not an employee this will not be required. A student ID should do.

However, since you are a student you will need to prove that you can fund your trip, a good bank account statement or a letter from the sponsor will be mandatory.

Comment: Also might help to provide a letter from the university stating how long your break is and when you're expected to resume studies (or the university starts its next term, if you're going in a mid-term break). I was asked about my summer break duration when I went for the visa interview and given a visa accordingly.